Unable to create session with Cassandra test container and Quarkus on Jenkins
I am trying to use the test container for Cassandra v 1.4.1 along with the latest datastax driver 4.17.0 along with JDK-17. I have successfully deployed the test container using UNIX socket /var/run/docker.sock.
However I still not able to build the session with cassandra. Please refer following steps for the details -

Starting cassandra
 List<String> portBindings = new ArrayList<>();
 portBindings.add("31044:9042");
 CassandraContainer cassandra=(CassandraContainer)new CassandraContainer(DockerImageName.parse("cassandra").withTag("4.1.4"));
 cassandra.addExposedPort(9042);
 cassandra.setPortBindings(portBindings);
 cassandra.start();



2 Build session

There are some logger before creating the session like -
    int port = cassandra.getMappedPort(CassandraContainer.CQL_PORT);
    logger.info("Port number").details("port",port);
    String host = cassandra.getHost();
    logger.info("Host name").details("host",host);
    InetSocketAddress contactPoint = cassandra.getContactPoint();
    logger.info("contactPoint").details("contactPoint",contactPoint.toString());

Logs output
  Port number [port=31044]
  Host name [host=172.17.0.1]
  [contactPoint=/172.17.0.1:31044]
  [datacenter=datacenter1]

Session creation
  session = CqlSession.builder()
       .addContactPoint(cassandra.getContactPoint())
       .withLocalDatacenter(getLocalDatacenter())
       .build();




Error logs

Failed to create the session because of following error

     2024-04-13 18:09:23,953 WARN  [io.net.cha.AbstractChannelHandlerContext] (s0-io-0) [] An exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to release id that hadn't been borrowed: 21584' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:: com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.protocol.FrameDecodingException: Error decoding frame for streamId 21584
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.protocol.FrameDecoder.decode(FrameDecoder.java:106)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:333)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.FrameTooLongException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 268435456: 825110825 - discarded

2024-04-13 18:09:23,966 WARN  [com.dat.oss.dri.int.cor.con.ControlConnection] (s0-admin-1) [] [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/172.17.0.1:31044, hostId=null, hashCode=2fa5e7df), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|id: 0xac094715, L:/10.253.224.13:55324 - R:/172.17.0.1:31044] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer))

Note
However on local minikube with docker it's working fine. This problem happen when running from jenkins pipeline try to execute the test.

Where the Jenkins is running? Can you describe more about network interface?
